# Muller method in Matlab doesn't find complex roots

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

My problem is that my Mullers method algorithm in Matlab doesn’t find the complex roots only real. It doesn’t matter which point I choose. My algorithm only finds -1.9713 in range [-2, 0] and 1.4660 in range [1 2] after using the roots function I know that roots are:

```
roots([2 0.5 -5 2 -3])

ans =

    -1.9713          
    1.4660          
    0.1276 + 0.7090i
    0.1276 - 0.7090i
```

Here is my code:

```
function [sol,sol2,i] = Muller2()
    min=-2;
    max=0;
    f=[2 0.5 -5 2 -3]
    x=min
for i=1:Inf
    %calculating coefficients of the quadratic equation
    a=polyval(polyder(polyder(f)), x)/2;
    b=polyval(polyder(f), x);
    c=polyval(f, x);

    %solving delta
    d=b^2-4*a*c;
    %calculating roots
    z1=-2*c/(b+sqrt(d));
    z2=-2*c/(b-sqrt(d));

    %choosing the closer root
    if(abs(polyval(f, z1))<=abs(polyval(f, z2)))
        x=x+z1;    
    else
        x=x+z2;
    end
    sol2(i)=x
    if(abs(polyval(f,x))<=20*eps)
        break;
    end
end

sol=x
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. In this fragment of code:

```
%choosing the closer root
    if(abs(polyval(f, z1))<=abs(polyval(f, z2)))
        x=x+z1;    
    else
        x=x+z2;
    end
```

I changed this:

```
if(abs(polyval(f, z1))<=abs(polyval(f, z2)))
```

to this:

```
if(abs(z1))<=abs(z2))
```

and the algorithm is now working correctly